# How to connect to Dropbox Api from yeoman generated app?

Tags: gruntjs, yeoman, dropbox-api, livereload

I use yeoman with livereload. And when I try connect to Dropbox Api I get error message in console.

```
The page at 'https://www.dropbox.com/1/oauth2/authorize?client_id=o6jnaqvlg5sa8et&redire…
alhost%3A9000%2F&response_type=token&state=oas_i0vcqifq_0.0u33q4s52f893sor' was loaded over
HTTPS, but ran insecure content from 'http://127.0.0.1:35729/livereload.js?
ext=Chrome&extver=2.0.9': this content should also be loaded over HTTPS.
```

My development url is localhost. I need your help!

Comment: What's the problem? Is something not working? Or are you just curious to understand the message?

Comment: I can't authentication and I don't understand this message

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dropbox token API returns "Missing client credentials" in Node.js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25573539/dropbox-token-api-returns-missing-client-credentials-in-node-js)